# where is control panel in ubuntu?

Tags: community, support

as seeing the title you have already known I'm a new Linux user. I was using windows for over 10 years now and wanted to switch to Linux to know it more. And for that I chose Ubuntu 20.04. But now I'm facing a problem with softwares in Ubuntu.
Like in windows we have a option called control panel which allows us to modify or remove softwares from windows right! But in Ubuntu I'm not seeing any option like that every time I have to install or remove any software I have to google it first then perform the action in terminal or by any GUI app.
If there is any option where I can monitor all my installed softwares and modify them at once please share it.
Thank Y

Comment: I think what you need is the Ubuntu software centre app which can be filtered for installed software only

Comment: @David The version of Ubuntu is in the question

Comment: @PonJar yes i see it now in that one very long sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked this on my installation. The app you need is simply called software. Its icon is like a blue and white case. When you open it there are three tabs at the top. The middle one is “installed”. If you select that it lists installed software, shows you the size of each and  provides a remove button